# htmlText embedded image gets blurry

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I have a following content in my htmlText field:

```
... <img src='xvmres://icons/hp/hp{{hp-ratio}}.png' width='28' height='10'/> ...
```

Everything is fine, but the image gets blurry. Where should I look? width/height are correct.

Comment: It might be because Flex loses focus on the image, just as it does when a popup is thrown and the background goes blurry. What container is your htmlText field in?

Comment: have you tried playing with bitmap smoothing? http://www.craftymind.com/2008/03/10/image-smoothing-in-flex/